# Execute sh in subdirectory from main.py script?

Tags: python, bash, path

I am trying to do the following thing.
I have a python project with this dir-tree:

```
Project dir
  |
  |___main.py
  |___module
       |
       |__a.py
       |__a.sh
```

`a.py` has a class with a method that runs the script:

```
class A():
    def run():
        os.system('a.sh')
```

And `a.sh` creates a file:

```
touch a.txt
```

And `main.py` instantiates an object of class `A` and calls `run()`:

```
a = A()
a.run()
```

When `main` is called, I get an error saying that the `script a.sh is not found`. I get why that happens, it's because the working dir is equal to the project root path, but how can I make it work so that the file created ends up in the root path?

I want to call `main.py` and end up with this configuration.

```
Project dir
  |
  |___a.txt
  |___main.py
  |___module
       |
       |__a.py
       |__a.sh
```

I could replace the call to `a.sh` in `a.py` to

```
os.system('module/a.sh')
```

And it would work, but it does not look clean to me.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't look clean? That's the directory it's in, so that's where you tell it to look.

Comment: you can create text files using python itself.

Comment: You could always alter the `PATH` environment variable, but personally I think that would be less clean.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the `a.py` module can extract the name of the directory it is in and use that in the `os.system()` call.  This is what I mean:

File `a.py`:

```
import os

class A():
    def run(self):
        my_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        script_path = os.path.join(my_directory, 'a.sh')
        os.system(script_path)

a = A()
a.run()
```